# "Is" versus "when" in tag wikis about tools

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

This question arose out of [my first tag wiki edit review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9010566). The edit added a one-line excerpt telling what the Galen framework is. I approved the edit, but another reviewer had rejected it, with the following standard reason:

> Simply defining what a [tag] *is* rarely helps those using it unless the tag's name itself is ambiguous. Excerpts should describe **why** and **when** a tag should be used. See the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts) for more guidance.

While I understand the concern, my gut feeling is that it doesn't apply to tag wikis about tools (as opposed to e.g. concepts). For tools, the extra clarifying remark would always be the same ("Only use this tag if your problem actually involves Galen, and not some other random framework."), and thus redundant. Is my interpretation correct, or should I have rejected the edit as well?

Comment: Lets put it this way: If you are using a hammer, wouldn't you know what the hammer is? What propose would I have telling you what a hammer is when you are asking a question about hammers, anyways?

Comment: @Braiam It might be slightly useful to readers and reviewers though (for instance, if for whatever reason I see a [galen] question while having no idea of what Galen is).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the edit should have been approved.

Markdown, and so links, doesn't work in excerpts and so they just look terrible and are useless, especially when you hover the tag, it's just messy instead of useful.
Even when the excerpt is displayed on the main wiki page they don't work.

Also, I don't think the text provided adds anything useful above it being blank.
Often, *something* is better than *nothing*, but this is not, and especially when you counter in the time taken to write it, and a bunch of people to review it. This is just a wasted opportunity.

---

Comparing the excerpt for CakePHP (for example) to Galen:

CakePHP:

> CakePHP is a rapid development framework for PHP that provides an extensible architecture for developing, maintaining, and deploying
>   applications. It uses commonly known design patterns like MVC and ORM
>   within the convention over configuration paradigm.

Galen:

> The [Galen Framework][1] is a framework that provides automated
>   testing of look and feel for responsive websites [1]:
>   http://galenframework.com/

The CakePHP excerpt provides enough info to be useful when I hover the tag around the site, to give me a quick idea of what it's about.

The Galen one tells me nothing at all, in fact the *only* info provided, "provides automated testing of look and feel for responsive websites", just causes me confusion and the need to even go elsewhere and clarify what the info provided means.

Comment: Good points, both of them. The best solution in this case, I reckon, would have been "Improve edit", but for tag wikis that only becomes available at 20k rep (as otherwise edits done by the reviewer would have to be reviewed themselves). As that was not an option, rejecting would have been the sensible decision.

Answer (score 2):

Well, first point: It's an *excerpt*, not a tag-wiki.
Thus there's very little space, and no support for anything but plain-text with whitespace-folding.

```
The [Galen Framework][1] is a framework that provides automated testing of look and feel for responsive websites

  [1]: http://galenframework.com/
```

Is thus be rendered as:

> The [Galen Framework][1] is a framework that provides automated testing of look and feel for responsive websites
>     [1]: http://galenframework.com/

That looks simply *awful*, right?

Now regarding a definition what it is and what it is for, that would be useful as nobody (within measurement error) knows that thing.
Something along the lines of:

> Automating testing of responsive websites using the Galen Framework

The URL should have been put in the body.

---

I have done those fixes, though as I'm unfamiliar with the subject, excerpt and wiki are still nothing to write home about.

Comment: I wasn't aware of excerpts not rendering links (I had overlooked the "You only have ~500 plain text characters for the excerpt [...] Save that for the 30,000+ character Markdown tag wiki." distinction in the [help center page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts), and never stopped to think why there never are links in the tag popups).