# Should a tag wiki excerpt be left empty, when there is no "why and when" to explain?

Tags: support, tags, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

I created a new tag yesterday, [dapper-contrib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dapper-contrib), and proposed both a tag wiki excerpt and tag wiki for it.

Tag wiki excerpt:

> Dapper.Contrib contains a number of helper methods for inserting, getting, updating and deleting records.

Tag wiki:

> Dapper.Contrib contains a number of helper methods for inserting, getting, updating and deleting records.
>
> Source: https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/tree/master/Dapper.Contrib

Currently, the tag wiki excerpt has one reject vote:

> Simply defining what a [tag] is rarely helps those using it unless the tag's name itself is ambiguous. Excerpts should describe why and when a tag should be used. [See the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts) for more guidance.

Am I correctly interpreting these guidelines, to not create a tag wiki excerpt when there is no *why* or *when* to explain?

Comment: If there is no *why* or *when*, can that tag really stand on its own? Does it really brings something a plain `[dapper]` tag would not?

Comment: Related: [“Is” versus “when” in tag wikis about tools](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300603/2751851). Your question is a better test case, though, as I had goofed up the review which my question is about for an unrelated reason.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi It's a separate library, so I figured it should have its own tag.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi In any case, the same question might be raised about the [dapper] excerpt: "Dapper is a micro-ORM for .NET developed and used by the Stack Overflow team, focusing on raw performance as the primary aim." (That's admittedly a more informative excerpt though.)

Comment: @Stijn, I'm not a tagging expert, but I'm not sure a library that adds a mere *nine* methods warrants its own tag. I'll let the taggers decide, though :)

Comment: I have had the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15564114 that's the first time this happened to me. I guess I'll leave the tag description empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it shouldn't be left empty in the end, but ...

I don't find your tag excerpt and wiki useful guidance when you're tagging a question with that tag. Both the excerpt and wiki should explain for question askers when and how to use the tag. Instead you have done what so many others have done before you: write an advertisement.

You can assume that the asker already knows what kind of library they are using. The excerpt and wiki should help them to write a good question bu guiding them on what to include, which other tags to consider and sometimes what NOT to ask.

A better excerpt could be:

> Use this tag for questions about the extension methods found in Dapper.Contrib and their usage with the Dapper ORM. Consider to add the tag Dapper as well. To report issues visit the github project.

I try to explain where to use it for, what other tags might be relevant and to not use it for reporting bugs.

The wiki could then be:

> The tag Dapper.Contrib should be used if your question is about any of the extension methods in the library, including but not limited to:
>
> - Get
> - Insert
> - Update
> - Delete
>
> The Dapper.Contrib is part of the ORM Dapper.
>
> If you're question is about or related to a specific dbms, like Sqlite or MSSql, don't forget to add that tag.
>
> Find the source [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/tree/master/Dapper.Contrib)
>
> The Github repository for Dapper is [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) where you can also report issues.