# Something wrong with the review path

Tags: discussion, review-queues

Today when I go to the review page, I get:

> You reviewed https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14843211 incorrectly. Please pay more attention to each review in future
>   Come back in 19 hours to continue reviewing.

When I follow that link, 1) I did that review 7 days ago, and 2) I approved it which is what it ended up being.

What am I missing?

Comment: You should have rejected it, for exactly the reason that the person who *did* reject it rejected it.

Comment: OK. Live and learn.

Comment: That tag smells.  Probably should be burninated.

Comment: +1 because I remember when [someone else asked](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341327/banned-for-failing-to-recognize-check-for-plagiarism-1st-time-draconian) about this same edit review last week, and "OK. Live and learn." is a much better response than the other person gave.

Comment: This is not just a duplicate, it's for the exact same review as the duplicate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the suggested edit ended up being approved by the reviewers... and it was [rolled back by a moderator](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41575454/revisions), who, in the process, manually banned you and probably all of the reviewers that approved the edit suggestion.

The reason is that the text being added to the wiki excerpt [was plagiarized](http://www.solver.com/integer-constraint-programming#Mixed-Integer%20Programming%20(MIP)%20Problems) from an external source. One of the reviewers correctly rejected the edit with this exact reason. Read more at [Let's stop tag wiki plagiarism](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313486/lets-stop-tag-wiki-plagiarism) and [Stopping tag wiki plagiarism, Part II: Taking Action](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318288/stopping-tag-wiki-plagiarism-part-ii-taking-action) to see why this is something the community wants to stop.

You can find some guidance on how to write good wiki excerpt [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262288/tag-excerpts-guideline) or [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338229/1743880). In short, you should try to explain when the tag should be used and what kind of questions should have it.