# Why was this descriptive tag excerpt rejected?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

Came across a question today that although using a technology I was familiar with some of what they were doing wasn't familiar to me and after a bit of digging identified they were also using something called Oracle Objects for OLE.
At which point I immediately looked for a Tag to add context to the question but couldn't find one, so decided to create one *(do not do this very often)*.

For the excerpt I've tried to be brief and describe what it is then in the Full Tag Wiki intend of expanding that description. But straight away in the [review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14402069) the first reviewer shoots me down stating;

> *Simply defining what a [tag] is rarely helps those using it unless the tag's name itself is ambiguous. Excerpts should describe why and when a tag should be used. [See the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts) for more guidance.*

So no content for a Tag Wiki is better then at least having something there as a starting point that can be improved, after all it's a "Wiki"?

If the advice this reviewer is giving is correct why is it most Tag Excerpts describe what they are rather then what they should be used for?, that information generally comes in the main Tag Wiki.

Comment: It's plagiarized from https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28378/intro.htm. Refer to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313486/lets-stop-tag-wiki-plagiarism and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318288/stopping-tag-wiki-plagiarism-part-ii-taking-action. Which doesn't explain why someone would reject with that reason, since there's a "copied content" reason, but explains why it should be rejected.

Comment: @Tunaki I didn't plagiarise it I linked the documentation in the Tag Wiki. It's a good description of what it is, you saying it I change that slightly they wouldn't have rejected it?

Comment: No idea why they rejected it -- it could be a reason. But, also, it also doesn't really explain when the tag should be used, and just gives a short description. See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262288/tag-excerpts-guideline

Comment: @Tunaki Which is why I said *"If the advice this reviewer is giving is correct why is it most Tag Excerpts describe what they are rather then what they should be used for?"*. You can't have one rule for one and one for another, surely anything other then blank is better?

Comment: It's a Tag excerpt, come on! I've modified the excerpt and still others are now rejecting it! There's only so many ways of saying *"Oracle Objects for OLE (OO4O) allows you to access data stored in Oracle databases with any programming or scripting language that supports Microsoft COM Automation and ActiveX technology. Some of these include Visual Basic, Visual C++, Visual Basic for Applications (VBA), IIS Active Server Pages (VBScript and JScript), and others that support COM automation."*! If I'd plagiarised an entire Tag Wiki then I could understand it, but this is just insane!

Comment: [*Should a tag wiki excerpt be left empty, when there is no “why and when” to explain?*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336899/2751851) offers an explanation for the rejection, though personally I'm still not convinced that the "Use this tag when..." boilerplate is always necessary. Though it is a bit of a XY question, the answers to [*“Is” versus “when” in tag wikis about tools*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300603/2751851) suggest a rather different approach.

Comment: Thanks @duplode good links will look through them, I've adjusted both the excerpt and body hopefully it will be acceptable.

Comment: @duplode I believe that boilerplate is removed when shown in the tag popup, but I can't find the reference where that is explained.

Comment: Keep in mind that there's a big difference between "I linked to the official documentation in the wiki" and "I made clear in the excerpt that the text in the excerpt was from another source and stated what that source is." As written, the excerpt *was* plagiarized. In any case, excerpts are too short for lengthy quotes and proper attribution. If you're using someone else's material in a tag excerpt, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @Lankymart Your mistake is in thinking that plagiarism is helpful. It's not; it's the opposite. When you plagiarize something, you're basically stealing. Then other people have to clean up the mess you've made. Please do edit tag excerpts and wikis, but please do not steal others' content to do it.

Comment: @Lankymart Plagiarism is plagiarism. Doing just a little of something wrong doesn't mean it's not wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first reviewer chose the "Lacks usage guidance" rejection reason. This is (at least technically) correct; the tag wiki excerpt lacks usage guidance.

The second and third reviewer rejected it with the "copied content" reason, and this is also correct—the content is taken straight from the official documentation.

The tag wiki excerpt *should* actually describe what "Oracle Objects 4 OLE" is, preferably in one's own words. If not those, then the first sentence  ("Oracle Objects...ActiveX technology") would suffice. A tag wiki excerpt should be as short as reasonably possible; we want askers and editors to read them. The more text they see, the less likely they are to read them.

I'll grant that the addition of usage guidance is tricky, though. The basic usage guidance would be "use this tag for questions about Oracle Objects 4 OLE", but that is so obvious that it doesn't add value.
If a tag is prone to being used wrongly, you could add a warning when **not** to use it.
Similarly, disambiguation can be helpful ("Do not use the Product-X-for-OLE tag if your question is only about Product-X-for-Dot-NET").

Comment: Still is a Tag with nothing better then a tag with something?

Comment: @Lankymart Really depends on what the "something" is. Given that the tool has a name (Oracle Objects 4 OLE) and an abbreviation (O4OO), it's useful to at least have these two in the tag wiki excerpt. That is better than nothing.